# Convert Rows into Dynamic columns using Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table, dynamic-sql

I have following information about real estate data in single table:

```
PropertyID
OwnerName
OwnershipDate
PropertyAddress
```

You can find sample data here [image: attached]

I want to `pivot` the results into desired output as follows

```
PropertyID      OwnerName     OwnershipDate                     OwnerName      OwnershipDate
0121320100011   RIVERA VICTOR   2018-02-06 00:00:00.0000000    RIVERA RAQUEL   2018-02-06 00:00:00.0000000
```

I want the number of columns to be dynamic as per number of owners found against each `PropertyID`.

**The efforts made so far are as bellow:**

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.OwnerName) 
            FROM owners_rec c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT   ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select   account,ownername
                from owners_rec
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(account)
                for ownername in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

*Helping hands are always loved :)*

Comment: 1.Use conditional aggregation to pivot 2 or more columns. 2. Compute max number of owners first. 3. assign different col names OwnerName1, OwnerName2 .. row_number() will help.

Comment: can you please modify the code for me?

Comment: Please follow https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17510.t-sql-dynamic-pivot-on-multiple-columns.aspx